# Is there any way to use Rails' video_tag and also provide image fallback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

I could not figure out how to add a fallback to Rail's video_tag method.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html

Is the only way to do this using raw html?

Comment: There is nothing else to the method. You cannot add a fallback with it.

Comment: Why not using a helper in order to do that ?